# Show toggle open on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am struggling with below code. All I want to do is have the slide out menu(  nav-container) open on page load, as at the moment its hidden until you open it with a click. How can I achieve this?

```js
$(window).load(function() {
       $(".btn-nav").on("click tap", function() {
         $(".nav-container").toggleClass("showNav hideNav").removeClass("hidden");
         $(this).toggleClass("animated");
       });
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn-nav">
    <div class="bar arrow-top-r"></div>
    <div class="bar arrow-middle-r"></div>
    <div class="bar arrow-bottom-r"></div>
    </button>
    
    <nav class="nav-container hidden hideNav">
      <ul class="nav-list">
        <li class="list-item"><a href=""><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a></li>
        <li class="list-item"><a href=""><i class="fa fa-credit-card-alt"></i></a></li>
        <li class="list-item"><a href=""><i class="fa fa-usb"></i></a></li>
        <li class="list-item"><a href=""><i class="fa fa-edge"></i></a></li>
        <li class="list-item"><a href=""><i class="fa fa-shopping-basket"></i></a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

call `click`:-

```
$(window).load(function() {
  $(".btn-nav").on("click tap", function() {
    $(".nav-container").toggleClass("showNav hideNav").removeClass("hidden");
    $(this).toggleClass("animated");
  }).click();
});
```

Comment: marking as correct by clicking the tick would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:**  Fire the click event (as mentioned in a previous answer)

**Option 2:** Remove the click event

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $(".nav-container").toggleClass("showNav hideNav").removeClass("hidden");
    $(this).toggleClass("animated");
});
```